# Trunk: browser does not copy-dir

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen

After running `trunk serve` command.
I've gotten the following:

[image: trunk build creation folder]

However, the folder doesn't appear in the browser resources.

(There is not any `trunk.toml` file)

[image: Browser folder]

Comment: AFAICT `trunk` bundles up your assets and serves them from the `/dist` subdirectory of your development directory. If you want `trunk` to add your assets from the `/asset` folder to the bundle, you have to explicitly tell it to do so. Read more about assets in `trunk` here: https://trunkrs.dev/assets/. I assume your `/asset` directory contains static files? Here is the relevant section from the asset documentation: https://trunkrs.dev/assets/#images-other-resources

Comment: Thanks for answering. the following folder has been created by `trunk`(I've used `data-trunk` & copy-dir). the files has been copid to the dist folder, However thier are not mount into the browser

Answer (score 0):

Came here for same issue.

Even you copy whole asset into dist folder doesn't mean you'll see it in chrome resouce section.

This seems awkward but solve my issue. Try to use different folder name other name **public**. I guess in your case might have different preserved name.

In index.html, add this copy dir command and retarget under **img** (or any other name).

```html
    <link data-trunk rel="copy-dir" href="public" data-target-path="img"/>
```

and with this path

```html
<img src="img/some_img.jpg" />
```

---

I'm digging more to find out why this happens.